# $u$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^N$ then if $T$ is an orthogonal transformation, $u\circ T$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Show that if $u$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if
>   $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is an orthogonal transformation then
>   $u\circ T$ is also harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Remember that an linear
>   transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is orthogonal if
>   $(^tT)T = T(^tT) = I$, the identity

What is $(^tT)T$? I think it's the orthogonal of $T$ multiplied with $T$.

Well, I'm looking into $p(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = (u\circ T)(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$

Here's what I did:

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_j}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial u}{\partial u_i}(T(x))\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}(x)$$

where $u_i = T_i$ because $u = (u_1,\cdots,u_n)$, I guess. (is there a better way to represent this)?

Then if we take the second derivative again (because we need the laplace operator)

$$\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x_j^2}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial u_k\partial u_i}(T(x))\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}(x) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial u_i}(T(x))\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j^2}(x)\right)$$

I need to sum this over $j=1,\cdots,n$ and prove it's $0$. I can also use $$\sum_{l=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_l^2} = 0$$

because $u$ is harmonic by hypothesis. Therefore when I sum over $j$ I can use the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial u}{\partial u_i}(T(x))\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j^2}(x)$ does not depend on $j$ and therefore

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial u}{\partial u_i}(T(x))\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j^2}(x) = 0$$

so I end up with

$$\Delta p = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x_j^2}(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial u_k\partial u_i}(T(x))\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}(x)\right)$$

I guess now I have to use the fact the the transformation is orthogonal. I think that $(^tT)T$ should play a role here but I can't even see the elements of $T$ in the sum I've ended with. Maybe it's not the orthogonal matrix so that's why I have no idea of what to do now.

**UPDATE:**

If I remember that $u_i = T_i$ and imagine $T_i$ as a matrix with coefficients $t_{ij}$ we have that $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial T_i}{\partial x_j} = t_{ij}$ so we end up with:

$$\Delta p = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x_j^2}(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial u_k\partial u_i}(T(x))t_{ij}\right)$$

In the PDF the user linked below, it takes the derivative with respect to the ith term and then with respect to the jth term. However I should take two times the derivative with respect to the ith, not mixed partials, because the divergence does not mix.

**UPDATE 2:**

Turns out I should have considered $T$ as beig linear from the beggining, I wouldn't need a product rule. And I also forgot The outer derivative when I did the second partial derivative, so it should be:

$$\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x_j^2}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial u_k\partial u_i}(T(x))\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}(x)\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}(x)\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial u_k\partial u_i}(T(x))t_{ij}t_{ij}\right)$$

but this doesn't seem right

Comment: Here's a link that works out the calculations: https://www.math.wisc.edu/~feldman/819/sol1.pdf

Comment: @TaisukeYasuda thanks. In the PDF however, it takes the second derivative with respect to another term, therefore making mixed derivatives. Do you have an idea why? It doesn't feel right. Please look at my update in the question

Comment: What's happening is, $T$ first mixes up all the original coordinates, so that all the derivatives now see all of the variables $x_j$ for $j=1,2,\dots,n$.

Comment: Related: [The Laplacian of the composition of a function with an orthogonal transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/983262)