# Given $u$ harmonic find all matrices $Q$ s.t. $u \circ Q$ harmonic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

More precisely, let $u \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ be harmonic, $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ matrix.

Classify $Q$ s.t. $u \circ Q$ harmonic.

I had a few ideas to find positive or counter examples but I have problems proving what a full classification would look like. First, orthogonal $Q$ should definitely work because the mean value property is conserved under rotation. Unless I messed up in my calculations I indeed managed to prove $\Delta (u \circ Q)=\Delta u \circ Q$ for orthogonal $Q$. Trivially, $Q=id$ and $Q=0$ satisfy the desired property as well.

However, I have trouble finding more classes of matrices that satisfy this. The closest I can get to an iff-type statement is the expression for $\Delta (u \circ Q)$ I derived when looking at orthogonal matrices:

$\Delta (u \circ Q) = \sum_{j,k=1}^{n}(\sum_{m=1}^{n}q_{ki}q_{ji})(\partial_{k}\partial_{j}u)\circ Q$

For orthogonal $Q$ and harmonic $u$ this is clearly zero. But unless I am missing something there could be a plethora of different ways this is zero for harmonic $u$.

Does anyone have tips?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983262/the-laplacian-of-the-composition-of-a-function-with-an-orthogonal-transformation

Comment: The only thing in this thread related to my question is the proof that the Laplacian is commutative for Q orthogonal, which I already said I managed to prove. But by doing that I only showed that orthogonal Q are one possible class of matrices, there could be more (no?).

Comment: The answer depends on $u$, for instance for $u$ constant any matrix $Q$ will work. If you want to find $Q$ which work for *all* harmonic *u*, it may help to pick a specific harmonic function and see what happens. Some more matrices that work are just rescalings of orthogonal matrices.

Comment: I see - sorry about that. It is true that if $ u \circ T$ is harmonic for **all** $u$ harmonic then $T$ is in fact orthogonal. If you have picked a specific function $u$ then there are many possible choices for $T$ as you've noticed.